# fastai - using 'untar_data' function in kaggle kernel

Tags: dataset, pandas, computer-vision, numpy, fastai

I have recently started with fastai lesson 1 and I am using kaggle to run the course notebooks. While going through the ‘lesson1-pets’ notebook we use `untar_data(URLs.PETS)` to get the data.

What I want to understand is where does this data get downloaded to?
As I can observe, after running the `untar_data(URLs.PETS)` function, it says downloading… ,the data gets downloaded, but nothing gets added to the data section of kaggle kernel.

Note: I am able to run the whole notebook in kaggle and just want to understand the working of untar_data function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes to `PosixPath('/root/.fastai/data/oxford-iiit-pet')` so you won't see it on the data pane.

Comment: Just to add, anything starting with a "." as a folder/dir is usually hidden in *nix..